# In Composite C1, How to apply same blog application/module to multiple pages

Tags: blogs, c1-cms

I have successfully added a blog application to a new page called "Blog". Now I have a different "AboutUs" page on which I want a list of latest five blogs postings. For this I created a new XSLT function similar to Community.Blog.Renderer which can display the blogs as per my requirement.

Next, I added blog application to "AboutUs" page. But it seems this is a different application. What I want to achieve:

1. A small widget on "AboutUs" page that displays list of latest 5 blogs posted on the "Blog" page.
2. A "Read More" button in each such widget, which when clicked will redirect to the corresponding blog on the "Blog" page.

I am new to composite C1 and till this far I have liked it very much. I hope, composite C1 can handle my requirements somehow and doesn't let me down.
Appreciating your concern.

Answer (score 2):

For keeping this thread clean, here is the answer posted by Inna on codeplex discussion forum:

You can achieve this by creating a simple XSLT:

1. Create XSLT for example named **Composite.Community.Blog.Latest**
2. On the **Function Call** tab add **two** functions "Composite.Community.Blog.Entries.**GetEntriesXml**" and "Composite.Community.Blog.**XsltExtensions**", Source code  like this

   ```
   <f:functions xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0">
   <f:function name="Composite.Community.Blog.Entries.GetEntriesXml" localname="GetEntriesXml">
       <f:param name="PropertyNames">
           <f:paramelement value="Date" />
           <f:paramelement value="Teaser" />
           <f:paramelement value="PageId" />
           <f:paramelement value="Id" />
           <f:paramelement value="Title" />
       </f:param>
       <f:param name="OrderByField" value="Date" />
       <f:param name="OrderAscending" value="False" />
       <f:param name="PageSize" value="5" />
   </f:function>
   <f:function name="Composite.Community.Blog.XsltExtensions" localname="XsltExtensions" />
   </f:functions>
   ```

   Make sure that **GetEntriesXml's Selected Fields** contain **PageId**, **Date** and **Title** fields, you will need them to generate Blog Entry URL.
3. On the **Template** tab you will have something like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0" xmlns:lang="http://www.composite.net/ns/localization/1.0" xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:be="#BlogXsltExtensionsFunction"  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl in lang f be">
       <xsl:template match="/">
       <html>
           <head></head>
           <body>
               <ul>
                   <xsl:for-each select="/in:inputs/in:result[@name='GetEntriesXml']/Entries">
                       <li>
                           <h3>
                               <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
                           </h3>
                           <p>
                               <xsl:value-of select="@Teaser" />
                           </p>
                           <a href="~/page({@PageId}){be:GetBlogUrl(@Date, @Title)}">Read more...</a>
                       </li>
                   </xsl:for-each>
               </ul>
           </body>
       </html>
       </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
4. Then insert this **XSLT** where you want to show list of the 5 latest blog entries. (**note**: you should not to add blog application to the  page where you want to show list of latest entries.)